# What condition to use Bollinger Bands?

Tags: php, trading, algorithmic-trading

I need to trigger a sales order when an asset touches the top row.
I need to trigger a purchase order when the asset touches the bottom line.

Looking at the chart I know the right moment to fire these orders, but in the programming that I wrapped, I do not know what criteria to use to know if an asset touched any of the lines.

[image]

Code:

```
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($candles as $c) {
        $arr[] = $c[4]; // Close price 
    }

    $result = trader_bbands ($arr, 21, 2.0, 2.0);
    $higher = end($result[0]);
    $medium = end($result[1]);
    $bottom = end($result[2]);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($higher, $medium, $bottom, $result);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

My return is this:

```
float(11343.933)
float(11202.999)
float(11062.065)
```

With this function I was able to extract the price of the asset for each line BOLL of the last candle, I just do not know how to know if it touched the line, could you help me?

Comment: How much close prices do you have in the array? I am trying to reproduce the 15M candles and become for the 3 values the same amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the mini-[php](/questions/tagged/php)-code-snippet, the solution is to evaluate this:

```
// DEFINES:
$PRICE_INDEX_OPEN = 1;
$PRICE_INDEX_HIGH = 2;
$PRICE_INDEX_LOW  = 3;
$PRICE_INDEX_CLOSE= 4;

// A BUY-ENTRY_______________________________________________________LONG?
if ( end($candles)[$PRICE_INDEX_LOW] <= $bottom ) { // .......... GO LONG
...
}

// A SELL-ENTRY______________________________________________________SHORT?
if ( end($candles)[$PRICE_INDEX_HIGH] >= $higher ) { // ......... GO SHORT
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "high" and "low" prices, which I assume you have in `$candles`, and use them in the following:

```
df[sell] = np.where( ( df['high'] >= df[upper BB] ), -1, 0 )
```

`-1` - indicate a short position initiated.

`0` - do nothing as criteria didn't match

Comment: @viniciussvl while you decided to click the [Accept], this answer is not correct. Besides strange mixing of python syntax with pandas and numpy tools inside the PHP-code context, the principle of answering just **SHORT**-entries **does not cover the LONG-entries at all** so one would hardly take this as a meaningful answer to your PHP-question. You may revise your previous [Accept] click and change the preferred answer to accept.